# Include AngularJs javascript files into Angular cli

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I have a legacy Angular JS application and now working in tandem with few new Angular 5 components using upgrade module. Following this post [here](https://medium.com/contentsquare-engineering-blog/angularjs-to-angular5-upgrading-a-large-application-7e6fbf70bafa)

Currently, I need to include all my AngularJs code into my `index.html`.
But, I want to include all JS files (more than 200) in my angular-cli.json in scripts section like below:

```
 "scripts": [
    "../appjs/**"
  ],
```

But, `ng-build` gives me error `no such file or directory:\appjs\**`.

How to include all the files in the folder in on go avoiding to include all the files one by one.

Here is the image of the folder structure. [image]

Please guide. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `src/appjs/**`?

Comment: @AlfMoh There is no src folder, I tried `../../ui/appjs/**` but in vain.

Comment: Can you try 'appjs/**' ? Your .angular-cli.json is in same level as appjs folder.

Comment: @chaoticmind doesn't :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the scripts: [] attribute doesn't accept globbing patterns. This is alluded to in [the documentation](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config):

> scripts:  An object containing JavaScript script files to add to the
>   global context of the project. The scripts are loaded exactly as if
>   you had added them in a  tag inside index.html.

So the alternative is to use a powershell script or DOS cmd to list the files and output them to the screen/file and then add all the necessary quotes to paste them into the scripts attribute in the config file.